# Azure Blob Storage Lifecycle Management - filter on folder

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azureportal

I'm playing with lifecycle management in Azure and trying to get it to move blobs to cool based on the folder they are in. The documentation on Azure says this is possible but they only provide examples of container prefixes. My question with this is, if it is possible and if so how do you define the filter?

My scenario is I have multiple containers with the same folder structure in each. E.G.
container1/folder1
container1/folder2
container2/folder1
container2/folder2

I need to be able to apply rules on folder level so the blobs in folder1 will go to cool after 1 day whilst in folder2 it moves to cool after 5 days (trivial example). It should ignore the container name as they are generated on the fly and I don't know the names of them, only the structure within them.

my current rule filter is like so "**/folder1" but this isn't moving anything. I've also tried just the folder name, E.G. "folder1"

Any idea what I'm missing? It's annoying that there's no instant feedback from Azure and I have to wait until the time it runs to find out whether it works (at least 24 hours)

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter rule must starts with a container name, and it does not support starting with folder name.

Please refer to this [Rule filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-powershell#rule-filters) link -> `prefixMatch` section, and here is the screenshot of Rule filters:

[image]

Comment: When creating the rule, the helper text seems to contradict this.
"A prefix match will find items like folders and blobs that start with the specified input. For example, inputting "a" would return any folders or blobs that start with "a". To find items in a specific container, enter the name of the container first, and then provide the desired prefix query for any contents within the container, for example: "myContainer/prefix"."

Comment: @scottdavidwalker,  You must specify the container name in the prefix. The description on the creating rule page is incorrect, it might mean that if you have a folder named `image`, then either of these rules like `container_name/i` or `container_name/image` can work(and they do work).

Comment: when rule runs than its calculating some extra cost in billing or its free ?

Comment: when rule runs than its adding some extra cost in billing or its free ?

Comment: @SaadAwan, The lifecycle management feature is free of charge. Customers are charged the regular operation cost for the Set Blob Tier API calls. Delete operation is free.. The link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#availability-and-pricing).